# Is there any way to add multiple labels to a node?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

Let's say I'm creating a database about food and in it, I want to add Dal which would be both Curry and Lentil.

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('menu', $$
        CREATE (:LENTIL:CURRY {name:"Dal"})
        $$) AS (dal agtype);
2023-02-20 06:49:01.568 IST [145143] ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":" at character 49
2023-02-20 06:49:01.568 IST [145143] STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM cypher('menu', $$
        CREATE (:LENTIL:CURRY {name:"Dal"})
        $$) AS (dal agtype);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 2:  CREATE (:LENTIL:CURRY {name:"Dal"})
```

That does not seem to be working.

It does not work with `SET` clause either: -

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('menu', $$
MATCH (dal:CURRY {name: "Dal Makhani"})
SET dal:LENTIL
RETURN dal
$$) AS (dal agtype);
2023-02-20 06:29:38.402 IST [145143] ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":" at character 80
2023-02-20 06:29:38.402 IST [145143] STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM cypher('menu', $$
    MATCH (dal:CURRY {name: "Dal Makhani"})
    SET dal:LENTIL
    RETURN dal
    $$) AS (dal agtype);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 3: SET dal:LENTIL
```

Is there any work-around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is not possible for now** but the work around you can use is treating that label as a **property** and make it as **an array type**, and keep the label unified for example a **:Person** has is working multiple jobs to get more money it will get a property called **{ jobs:["Teacher", "Football player"] }**

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned creating a node with multiple labels is not supported by Apache AGE as of yet however, there's definitely some work arounds that you can use. Here's my suggestions:

- You can try assigning properties to the node instead of labels that way you might be able to achieve the same functionality.
- Another solution could be to have separate nodes and have a relationship between them. DAL can have a label "Food" and Curry and Lentil can have a label "Category" with a *BELONGS_TO* relationship between them.

Only you can decide what works best for your case as these are just suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create multi-label vertices in Apache AGE at the moment, But you can try assigning properties Like you can assign properties to a node using the `SET` clause to the node instead of labels that way you might be able to achieve the same functionality